# "lvalue required as left operand of assignment " error

Tags: c

The following code produces a "lvalue required as left operand of assignment"

```
if( c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'  || c = " " || c = ",") {
```

I assume I'm writing this wrong, what is wrong? and how would I write it correctly?

Comment: The code you have shown cannot produce the diagnostic you are getting, unless `c` is a macro that expands to a non-lvalue.  If `c` is declared as a plain variable, `c = " "` should produce "incompatible types in assignment" or something similar.  My guess is that in your actual code you're using `f() = " "` (i.e., a function's return value instead of `c`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use single quotes for chars and do double equals for equality (otherwise it changes the value of c)

```
if( c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'  || c == ' ' || c == ',') {
```

Furthermore, you might consider something like this to make your boolean logic more clear:

```
if( (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')  || c == ' ' || c == ',') {
```

Although your boolean logic structure works equivalently (&& takes precedence over ||), things like this might trip you up in the future.

Comment: FWIW, I'd use `('A' <= c && c <= 'Z')` to make that bit of logic clearly show that 'A' and 'Z' are the 'outer' bounds and have the expression most resemble the math-style 'A' <= c <= 'Z'

Answer (score 4):

equality is `==`, `=` is assignment. You want to use `==`. Also `""` is a `char*`, single quotes do a character.

Also, adding some parens to your condition would make your code much easier to read. Like so

```
 ((x == 'c' && y == 'b') || (z == ',') || (z == ' '))
```

Answer (score 2):

`=` is the assigning operator, not the comparing operator. You are looking for `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer the minimalist style:

```
((x == 'c' && y == 'b') || (z == ',') || (z == ' '))

(  x == 'c'  &&  y == 'b'   ||   z == ','   ||   z == ' '  )
```

or

```
(  x == 'c'  &&  y == 'b'  ?  z == ','  :  z == ' '  )
```

against

```
( x == 'c' && y == 'b' ? z == ',' : z == ' ')
```

Comment: !!! the html washine has skipped the dubble space around logical operators !!!!  ---  and that makes all the visible difference ---