# Why a++=5 is error?

Tags: c, operator-precedence

I just wrote a code in c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a=0;
    option1: a++=5;
    option2: ++a=5;
    printf("%d\n",a);

    return 0;
}
```

but it doesnt compiled with error

```
lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

why its an error?
thanks!

Comment: `option1: a++=5;` is not a C code.

Comment: @Vagish Actually it is. Goto labels!

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: he is trying to achieve something like `a=6=5`.This is not valid.

Comment: Oh now I see,sorry for the confusion.Comment was not about label.

Comment: Thank you all, I'm pretty new in C and I tried my best to search but it's a problem to write "a++=" in google..

the downvote is It is quite insulting....

Comment: You might have been downvoted because neither "option" actually makes sense (in other words: we don't even know what you are trying to do). It is often a good idea to explain what you are attempting to do.

Comment: Maybe it was downvoted for the lack of research, a search for the error message gives a bunch of results, and (after some research about what an lvalue is) the error message is quite self-explanatory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because, like your compiler says, `a++` is not an `lvalue`, it's a `rvalue`.
You will find more information about `lvalue` and `rvalue` [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c).

Answer (score 4):

A **variable** is a **name associated to a storage**. When you define a variable you associates a symbol to a reserved storage. In a program you can use the name of a variable at different places. In an arithmetic expression, like `a+1`, `a` refers to the **value stored** in the memory associated to the symbol. When you use it in an assignment like `a=3`, `a` refers to the **storage location**.

When the symbol is used to denote the value, it is said to be an **r-value** (right value, *value* at the right of an assignment), when the symbol is used to denote the location, it is said to be an **l-value** (left value, *value* at the left of an assignment). In `a=b`, `a` is a l-value and `b` a r-value.

You can only have l-values at the left of an assignment, alas `a++` is an expression that denotes the value of the variable before the increment, not the location, so you can't put it on the left of an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

well a++ simply is a shortcut to write a=a+1 nothing more than that.
there is a difference in a++ and ++a but both ultimately add 1 to initial value of the variable (here that variable is a).a++=5 is not a valid syntax.
example:
suppose we have a initial value a=3, now if you write a++ == 5(note == which means equals to in coding) it means 4==5 which is not true.
but since you're using "=" your code doen't make any sense to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a valid syntax.

```
a++; //it will give 1. so after that you are assinging
```

So it is like

```
1=5;
```

It will give you the error. Refer this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162438/lvalue-required-as-left-operand-of-assignment)

Answer (score -1):

a++=5 is the same as (a++)=5

And (a++) will evaluate to 1, and you can't do 1=5

Comment: `a` itself evaluates to 0. Still `a = 5;` is valid although "you can't do" `0 = 5;`.