# Problems with Arduino Attiny84 and Timer1

Tags: timer, arduino, attiny

I've got an error that I can't find in any library:

In function

`'void__vector_2()'`

> error lvalue required as left operand of assigment.

Comment: Please show the code that causes the error.

Comment: Unclear, Please post the code or Minimal version of it..

Comment: Are you accidentally using a single `=` instead of two in a comparison like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162438/lvalue-required-as-left-operand-of-assignment)? Are you trying to assign something to variables  for which it makes no *"sense to change the value. (...) incomplete types, const variables, array names, and structures/unions with a const element somewhere in there."*? [Source](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/134604-error-lvalue-required-left-operand-assignment.html)

Comment: The Problem was a too long code! Fixed by Resizing Memory structure!