# possible assignment in condition (C)

Tags: c, gcc

I have to find is the number "a" a two-digit odd. Mistake comes on if

```
#include <stdio.h>
main ()
{
    int a,k;
    int count=0;
    printf ("input number \n", a);
    scanf ("%d", &a);
    k = a % 2;
    while (a)
    {
        a /= 10;
        count ++;
    }
    if (k = 1 && count = 2)
        printf ("It is \n");
    else
        printf ("It is not \n");
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Not an exact duplicate of ["lvalue required as left operand of assignment " error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050132/lvalue-required-as-left-operand-of-assignment-error) but same first-day-of-CS-101 problem.

Comment: @Nick: It may be a good idea to have the literal you are comparing with as the lvalue like in your current case i.e. use `if ( 1 == k )` instead of `if ( k == 1 )`, this way in case you miss out one "=" you will get a compile time error.

Comment: Also as a habit for the start, always use a correct signature for `main`. It should be `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` or nothing else.

Comment: @another.anon.coward Or, better yet, just compile with the `-Wall` and `-Werror` flags, which produces a compile error with either statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is here:

```
if (k = 1 && count = 2)
```

you probably meant:

```
if (k == 1 && count == 2)
```

`=` is an assignment. `==` is a comparison for equality.

Also, the loop is not necessary. You can check if the number is two digits by checking if it's less than 100 and greater than or equal to 10.

Answer (score 1):

GCC is complaining about this:

```
if (k = 1 && count = 2)
```

The equality operator is a double equals sign: `==`. What you've used, the single equals sign `=`, is the assignment operator.

You are setting `k` to 1 and `count` to 2, and that `if` will always be executed.

The message you're getting is designed to help people quickly catch exactly this problem.