# Strange error: non-lvalue in assignment in C++

Tags: c++

Here is my program that find a rectangle's area, perimeter, and if the rectangle is square. It does all this by using two coordinates and modeling structs. I am fairly new to C++ and I am getting an unfamiliar error on this line: if(abs(y-a2.y) = abs(a2.x - x) ) { The error says this: non-lvalue in assignment.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

/*
Name: Rectangle
Author: ------
Date: 27/10/14 04:31
Description: A program that finds the area, perimeter, and if a rectangle is square
*/

using namespace std;

class Point
{
private:
    int x, y;

public:

    Point ()
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }

    //A four parameter constructor

    Point (int a, int b)
    {
        x = a ;
        y = b ;
    }

    //Setter function

    void setX (int a)
    {
        x = a ;
    }

    void setY (int b)
    {
        y = b ;
    }

    //Accessor functions

    int getX ()
    {
        return x ;
    }

    int getY ()
    {
        return y ;
    }

    //Function to print points

    void printPoint ()
    {
        cout << endl << "(" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl ;
    }

    //Function to enter new points

    Point newPoint ()
    {
        Point aPoint;
        int a;
        int b;
        cout << "Enter first x coordinate: " ;
        cin >> a ;
        cout << "Enter first y coordinate: " ;
        cin >> b ;
        aPoint.setX(a);
        aPoint.setY(b);
        return aPoint;
    }

    //Function to find area

    int areaA (Point a2)
    {
        int height = y - a2.y ;
        int length = a2.x - x ;
        int area = abs((length * height)) ;
        return area ;
    }

    //Function to find perimeter

    int perimeterA (Point a2)
    {
        int height1 = y - a2.y ;
        int length1 = a2.x - x ;
        int perimeter1 = abs(((length1 + height1) * 2)) ;
        return perimeter1 ;
    }

    //Function to determine shape

    int isSquare (Point a2)
    {
        int square;
        if ( abs(y - a2.y) = abs(a2.x - x) )     //****ERROR ON THIS LINE****
        {
            cout << "It is square" ;
        }

        else
        {
            cout << "It is not square" ;
        }
        return square;
    }
};

Point newPoint();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "Enter top left coordinate first and bottom right coordinate second" ;
    cout << endl << endl ;
    Point firstPoint;
    Point secondPoint;
    int areaR;
    int perimeter;
    firstPoint = firstPoint.newPoint();
    secondPoint = secondPoint.newPoint();
    cout << endl ;
    cout << "First point: " ;
    firstPoint.printPoint();
    cout << "Second point: " ;
    secondPoint.printPoint();
    cout << endl ;

    areaR = firstPoint.areaA(secondPoint);
    cout << "Area: " << areaR << endl ;
    perimeter = firstPoint.perimeterA(secondPoint);
    cout << "Perimeter: " << perimeter << endl;

    cout << endl ;
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: equality is checked by a `==` not `=`

Comment: *"I am getting an unfamiliar error on this line: if(abs(y-a2.y) = abs(a2.x - x) ) { The error says this: non-lvalue in assignment. I am not sure what this means or how to fix it."*  Did you perhaps do an Internet search on ["lvalue"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)#lrvalue) to see what the word meant?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["lvalue required as left operand of assignment " error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050132/lvalue-required-as-left-operand-of-assignment-error) (that question is for c but the rules are same in this case)

Comment: So the next logical thing to ask yourself is "Is that an assignment? Is it supposed to be?".

Comment: @HostileFork: A really bent `op=`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71dfb0ed9bc208d6

Comment: @Deduplicator Well...auto_ptr made it into the standard library.  <shrug>

Comment: @HostileFork Ok, then my link is only a contender. I had succeeded in forgetting that abomination...

Answer (score 4):

```
if(abs(y-a2.y) = abs(a2.x - x) )
```

tries to assign `abs(a2.x - x)` to `abs(y-a2.y)` which does not make sense. Use `==` to compare values.

By the way, `isSquare` returns an uninitialized value which is a mistake. Either return something meaningful of make the function `void`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything strange in that error. That line does indeed attempt to assign something to a non-lvalue, exactly as the error message states. Equality comparison operator is spelled as `==` in C++. A single `=` in expression context is assignment operator.

It is also unclear why you are mixing two different styles when including the C library headers: `<cstdlib>` and `<math.h>`. If you decided to include `<cstdlib>`, then including `<cmath>` would make more sense. Keep in mind though that standard library functions available through `<c...>` headers should be treated as members of `std` namespace. Including `.h` version of heqaders is deprecated in modern C++.